# calculating percentiles for transformation into standard normal quantiles

Tags: data-transformation, normality-assumption, quantiles

I'm trying to hand calculate a standard normal quantile plot.  The first step involves transforming the data into percentiles.  That sounded like the easy part, but apparently there are several calculations usable.

(i - 0.5)/n                :1.Hazen

(i - 0.375)/(n + 0.25)     :2.Blom

(i - 1)/(n - 1)            :3.??

(i) / (n + 1)              :4.Weibull Gumbel

I'm not going to use #3 since that generates a 0% value, which makes it difficult to transform by the inverse standard normal.

The major differences are only observable at the ends, in which case, #4 has the smoothest transition, while #1 has the most extreme values at the ends.

What would be the reason to use any single one of these calculations over the others?

Comment: If I remember right, the package R has nine definitions available for its quantile function. Yours there are all of the form $\frac{i-\alpha}{n+1-2\alpha}$ with $\alpha = \frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{8},-1$ and $0$ respectively. Which you might choose depends on what properties you want. For example, values of $\alpha$ close to $\frac{1}{3}$ give close to the median of the distribution of uniform order statistics (see the [median of the Beta](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution)) - medians are convenient to consider because they survive monotonic transformation. ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd) ... I believe $\alpha=3/8$ was suggested for normal quantiles because it gave something near to expected quantiles in that case. What properties do you want? You can always investigate how they behave for whatever you're trying to do via simulation at typical sample sizes.

Comment: Great suggestion.  I injected random normal values then converted them by the three methods above (1,2,4) into percentiles and then converted them back by the inverse normal function.  I repeated this 100 times with both 10,000 injected points and at 50 injected points.  I then ran simple linear correlation between the original values and the converted values and summarized by method over the 100 runs.  Based on this, it looks like Method 1 has the closest match to the original injected values, although Method 1, 2 are VERY close.  Method 3 is the least accurate, but still VERY close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Solomon and Sawilowsky (2009)](http://digitalcommons.wayne.edu/jmasm/vol8/iss2/9/) compared several of these Rank-based Inverse Normal transformations.  They recommended the first technique because it more accurately reproduced the target moments.  Note that the first technique, (i-.5)/n, is usually attributed to Chester Ittner Bliss and referred to as the Rankit transformation. Of course, the differences among these techniques are quite small, especially as n becomes large, and the differences primarily occur with the even moments.

References:

Solomon, S. R., & Sawilowsky, S. S. (2009). Impact of rank-based normalizing transformations on the accuracy of test scores. Journal of Modern Applied Statistical Methods, 8(2), 448-462.